# How to use submodules in codeigniter HMVC?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I want to use submodules Codeigniter HMVC. I want to create the following structure in my project.

```
modules
│   ├── module1
│   │   ├── admin
│   │   │   ├── controllers
                ├────── Home.php
│   │   │   ├── models
│   │   │   └── views
│   │   ├── subadmin
│   │   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   ├── models
│   │   │   └── views
│   │   └── worker
│   │       ├── controllers
│   │       ├── models
│   │       └── views
│   └── module2
│       ├── admin
│       │   ├── controllers
│       │   ├── models
│       │   └── views
│       ├── subadmin
│       │   ├── controllers
│       │   ├── models
│       │   └── views
│       └── worker
│           ├── controllers
│           ├── models
│           └── views
```

When I call my home controller by using the below URL

`http://localhost/myname/projectname/module1/admin/home`

It takes me to `404 default` CI page.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Configuration code, setup etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily an HMVC setup. 
Please do the below set up
https://github.com/natanfelles/codeigniter-hmvc

Comment: We already use HMVC. Please look at my directory structure. There is submodules in module

Comment: 1.The structure is fine, but you should add the helper file like third_party, and related files
2. Add correct .htaccess file into the project

Comment: SO you mean to say. I only need to fix my htacess

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create nested modules - which technically isn't prossible

Try this instead:

```
  modules |          |             |       |          
          | module 1 |             |       |          
          |          | controllers |       |          
          |          |             | admin |          
          |          |             |       | Home.php 
          |          | models      |       |          
          |          | views       |       |          
          | module 2 |             |       |          
          |          | controllers |       |          
          |          |             | admin |          
          |          |             |       | Home.php 
          |          | models      |       |          
          |          | views       |       |
```

It should work with your before mentioned url.